# Storing cookie value in global variable in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies

I've an ASP.NET MVC blog, in order to show the posts and comments dates in client timezone a cookie is used, the cookie contains the client timezone offset. When the server receives a request it will read the offset value from cookie and changes all the dates accordingly before sending to browser. My question how I can store the cookie in a global variable on every request so that it can be accessed by any where for date adjustment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a session variable if you don't want to use the cookie every time

```
session["MyVarName"] = mycookievalue
```

then you can access the session every time needed.

You can also think of implementing e custom modelbinder so you can bind your session's value to a model. (for example a class UserSettingsModel)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the more controller and action depend on values supplied from outside, the more unit testable and robust they become. I would do it this way

First, create model that holds settings for timezone

```
public class ClientTimeZoneSettings
{
   public string TimeZoneName {get; set;} // or whatever
}
```

Then, create model binder. That Model binder will be used to extract values from cookie

```
public class ClientTimeZoneSettingsModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("timeZoneName"))
        {
            bindingContext.Model = new ClientTimeZoneSettings {TimeZoneName = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["timeZoneName"]; }
        }

    }
}
```

Register that model binder in Global.asax

protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

```
RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ClientTimeZoneSettings), new ClientTimeZoneSettingsModelBinder());
```

}

And the main point. In all your actions that require those settings, you can directly use `ClientTimeZoneSettings` as a parameter

```
public ActionResult ShowComments(ClientTimeZoneSettings settings)
{
  // use settings
}
```

**UPDATE:** Significantly simpler approach:

Install [MvcFutures](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Mvc3Futures) from nuget. It contains `CookieValueProviderFactory` that will automatically inspect cookies for values when model binding. To use it, simply add into `ValueProviderFactories`

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new CookieValueProviderFactory());
}
```

And then name your parameter accorting to cookie name

```
public ActionResult ShowComments(string timeZoneName)
{
    // timeZoneName will contain your cookie value
    return View();
}
```